# How to create Grouped and Stack (both) using flow chart?

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

I can draw Grouped or stack flow chart but cant combine them
like this:

[image: bar-plot]

Can you help me, thank you

Comment: This question needs more information. Please create a code snippet or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows what you have tried and what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group stacked bars, you need to include the [orderBars](https://github.com/pkoltermann/SideBySideImproved) and [stacked](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/stacking/) plugins (in that order).

You then need to add a `stack` and `bars.order` property to each of your series to allow the ordering and stacking, like so:

```
var series = [{
    data: [[0, 35], [1, 70], [2, 33]],
    stack: 1,
    bars: {
        order: 1
    }
}, {
    data: [[0, 35], [1, 20], [2, 33]],
    stack: 1,
    bars: {
        order: 1
    }
}, {
    data: [[0, 30], [1, 10], [2, 34]],
    stack: 2,
    bars: {
        order: 2
    }
}, {
    data: [[0, 35], [1, 70], [2, 33]],
    stack: 2,
    bars: {
        order: 2
    }
}];
```

The options above will stack the first two series object together and the second two series objects together, with the first two stacked series ordered before the second two stacked series. An example of stacking bars can be found at [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aadm7o5g/2/).

Replacing the xaxis values with custom values can be done by setting the `xaxis.ticks` property:

```
var options = {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: .2
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        tickSize: 1,
        ticks: [
            [0, "A"],
            [1, "B"],
            [2, "C"]
        ]
    }
};
```